# Unable to call submit function of Jquery below is the HTML and jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am unable to call submit function of jQuery below are the HTML And jQuery code

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //global vars
    var userName = $("#username"); //user name field
    var userPass = $("#password");//password field
     //When form submitted
    $("#overlay_form1").submit(function () {
        window.alert("Please fill UserName & Password!");
        return false;
    });
    //open popup
    $("#pop").click(function () {
        $("#overlay_form1").fadeIn(500);
        positionPopup();
    });
    //close popup
    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#overlay_form1").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup() {
    if (!$("#overlay_form1").is(':visible')) {
        return;
    }
    $("#overlay_form1").css({
        left : ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form1').width()) / 2,
        top : ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form1').width()) / 7,
        position : 'absolute'
    });
}
//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize', positionPopup);
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#" id="pop" >PopUp</a>
<br />
<form id="overlay_form1" name="overlay_form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <h2> Put your contents here..</h2>
    <label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br /><br />
    <label>Password: </label><input type="text" name="password" id="password"/><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Login" />
    <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>

</form>
```

Comment: You can pass the HTML code too? Or do you have a fiddle or something? Any errors when you try this?

Comment: I m getting no error, instead alert window also unable to popup..... $("#overlay_form1").submit(function()
          {
      window.alert("Please fill UserName & Password!");


    return false;
  });

Comment: @Pavnesh I think the requirement of above code is not clear. First try to explain why You are using that code? What output You want.

Comment: @Pavnesh: use '<input type="submit" value="Login" />' instead '<input type="button" value="Login" />' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a submit button.
Change your

```
<input type="button" value="Login" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

and it should work.